# Doesn't finish booting after failed auto-login set-up attempt

Tags: raspbian, boot

I am using Raspbian and I am trying to get it so I don't have to enter a username and password every time I switch on. I tried replacing:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1
```

with:

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty2 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

in /etc/inittab. Now when i turn it on, it does a lot of loading up, but stops after:

```
[ ok ] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
```

and I can't do anything, apart from pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del which causes it to reboot. How do I get it back to how it was/get it to login automatically? Is there anyway I can get a terminal from here?

The only other changes to the system I have made are installing a few Perl modules, and re-sizing the partitions on the SD card.

Thanks.

Comment: _Is there anyway I can get a terminal from here?_ It seems an SSH server is already running (`[ ok ] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.`). Did you try to log into your RPi through SSH?

Comment: No I haven't. I haven't done it before or done anything to set that up, will it work 'out of the box'? I'll try it when I get home. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to login to my Raspberry Pi through SSH.
To do this I downloaded PuTTY from [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). 
Aparently SSH is enabled by default on Raspbian.

It turned out I hadn't made the changes quite right, I had written:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty -f pi tty2 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

instead of:

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty2 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Thanks to @Morgan for pointing me in the right direction.